# Google Chrome does not run after change the profile

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome does not work after the profile on my PC changed by joining my PC to a domain.

It does not show any message or error. Just nothing run.

Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you installed it via [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). Install it through ClickOnce again.

Chrome is typically installed via ClickOnce, which installs for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible you have a whole new account. When you join a domain and sign on with domain creds, Windows won't load the local account.

Either way, you'll have to reinstall Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome normal installer installs it only for local user. When you joined in a domain Windows created a new folder for you profile threating you as a new user (you can join to local machine profile through respective option on logon screen to enter in your old account and see that Chrome is functioning).

Two solutions:

- [Install Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/Chrome) again for the new user - this solution will install Chrome only for this user profile
- Install a portable version of Google Chrome (e.g. install [LiberKey](http://www.liberkey.com) and then install Google Chrome portable app on it or install a portable version directly from [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)) - this solution will install Chrome for all user profiles if you allow access of other users to its folder and shortcut, but with the same Chrome profile